# Display 3 recent posts from one taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a Custom Post Type - "magazine_entry" and have registered the taxonomy "division".  I have then created several divisions such as, "international", "tokyo", "kansai", etc...

I am trying to display the 3 most recent posts from a single taxonomy of the custom post type.

For example, have

(i will handle the css and html later)

```
International:
post 1      post 2     post 3    

Tokyo:
post 1      post 2     post 3
```

etc...

I can get all posts from the custom post type to show up, but I don't know how to get the posts from just one of the taxonomies.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Taxonomy Parameters available in WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). For example, to get the three recents `magazine_entry` posts having the `international` term slug, you can use:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'magazine_entry',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'division',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'international'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Great!  Of course it is that simple.  I always look for the hard and gritty solutions =/  Now I will start to work on turning the posts per page into Epanel options.

Comment: In addition, could you tell me where to start in terms of setting a loop that will for example, display the 3 most recent posts from all of the taxonomy categories, automatically, rather than having to set up a new loop each time I make a new category?

Comment: Get all your terms using [`get_terms('division')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).